# WPF - show an image and set different clickable areas on it

Tags: wpf, image, wpf-controls

the case is this one:

I have an image representing a schema, let's say a cross like the following
[image: cross shape image]

I need to include the image in a WPF UserControl and let the user click on each of the branches (red, green or blue...) and, according to the branch selected, do something different.

What would be the best way to solve this?

I tried with canvas but I don't find a way to trace correctly the background image with shapes (also because the real image is not so simple as the sample cross here)

thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Such a simple thing I would rebuild with Grid and Border.

Comment: infact I have written that the real image is more complex. Thanks anyway for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the comlexity of shapes but it is not difficult to find the shape where mouse up event is fired by `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` method.

Let's say there is a Canvas which has two Rectangles inside.

```xml
<Canvas Background="Transparent"
        PreviewMouseUp="Canvas_PreviewMouseUp">
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect1" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20"
               Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Red"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect2" Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="80"
               Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Green"/>
</Canvas>
```

Catching its PreviewMouseUp event, you can tell the Rectangle where that event is fired.

```cs
private void Canvas_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender);
    var result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest((Visual)sender, position);
    if (result.VisualHit is Rectangle rect)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Hit {rect.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem I have found with rectangles is how to "cover" a diagonal area (so how to manage rotation for example). As I sad, the background image could include something more complex. Maybe I was not clear with my simple example image.
Anyway thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You are still not clear why rotation matters. The shape of visual element does not affect its hit test capability. Are you having trouble to define a rectangle or other shape to cover the area to receive mouse event?

Comment: thanks for your help, seems that since my question has been downgraded I cannot add details to the description (a more real image). I'll try to manage some how... you have been kind to answer

Comment: If you are struggling with creating a Canvas filled with some rectangles or other shapes to reproduce a particular image, it would be better to post it as another question.

Comment: honestly I'm worried to be downgraded too much :( My question regarded the best method to be used to accomplish the task. You are the only real suggestion, and the way seems to keep going with canvas: put the image as background, create rectangles (or circles...) with transparent fill and make this areas clickable. thanks again for the support